# How to make a Flutter button log to the console when pressed?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm coming from JavaScript where every other line is `console.log('Logged!')`. How is this done in Flutter? The [Flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/code-debugging) show there is a `log()` feature. I tried to make a button log to the console when clicked but it didn't work.

I'll show the code snippet first, then the error message, then the full code.

```java
import 'dart:developer';

ElevatedButton(
          style: style,
          onPressed: () => {
            log('Clicked!');
          },
          child: const Text('My Button'),
        ),
```

The error message:

```
lib/main.dart:45:27: Error: Expected '}' before this.
            log('Logged!');
                          ^
```

And my full code:

```java
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:developer';

void main() => runApp(const HelloWorld());

class HelloWorld extends StatelessWidget {
  const HelloWorld({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const String appTitle = 'MyApp';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(appTitle)),
        body: const FullNameField(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FullNameField extends StatelessWidget {
  const FullNameField({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ButtonStyle style = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20));

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          // alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Enter your username',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          style: style,
          onPressed: () => {
            log('Clicked!');
          },
          child: const Text('My Button'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Thanks!
```

Comment: I think you should be using `print`, instead of `log`. Also, you may need to change the closure from `onPressed: () => {` to `onPressed: () {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`debugPrint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/debugPrint.html)

> Prints a message to the console, which you can access using the "flutter" tool's "logs" command ("flutter logs").

```dart
onPressed: () => {
  debugPrint("Logged!"),
},
```

Also, you can use `print()` method, which I is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a semi-colon at the end of `log('Clicked!');`. When I changed the semi-colon to a comma it worked. I'm coming from JavaScript. :-)

```java
 ElevatedButton(
          style: style,
          onPressed: () => {
            log('Clicked!'),
          },
          child: const Text('Get Fortune'),
        ),
```

And `debugPrint('Clicked!'),` and `print('Clicked!'),` also work.

--

I just figured out that the arrow function has to be followed by commas but without the arrow function you use semi-colons.

```java
onPressed: () {
    
            log('Clicked!');
          },
```

vs.

```java
onPressed: () => {
    
            log('Clicked!'),
          },
```

Comment: When you introduce braces, the statements between it must be terminated with semicolon. However, after a fat arrow you can use just a single statement or expression without braces as in: `onPressed: () => log('Clicked!'),`